# Iran nuclear sanctions lifted or intensified after implementation of the JCPOA agreement

Tags: iran, jcpoa

Is Iran nuclear sanctions lifted after the nuclear deal?

because recently I spoke with several Iranian scientists and they told me that

> it doesn't happened, Iran sanctions is not lifted, infact we feel it is intensified.

Comment: For those who don't know (myself included) what the JCPOA agreement is, could you add some context for it to your question?

Comment: @Bradley Wilson Under the JCPOA agreement, limits were put on Iran’s nuclear activities in exchange for, among other things, the removal of all nuclear-related sanctions imposed on the Islamic Republic

Comment: The question assumes that it's a binary situatoin (as opposed to, a certain set of sanctions lifted and a certain set not)

Comment: "the removal of all nuclear-related sanctions imposed on the Islamic Republic"  This seems unlikely.  They wouldn't have wanted to remove the nuclear science sanctions, as those are the ones preventing nuclear research.  The JCPOA would have lifted the *economic* sanctions.  So Iran could sell oil and buy food and medicine but not do nuclear research.  Perhaps people simply had unrealistic expectations.